# AngularJS - text on button in SVG not appearing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg

I'm trying to add a button to SVG file in AngularJS directive. My problem is that the button text is not appearing. Here is my code:

```
function makeElement(namespace, tag, attrs) {
   var el= document.createElementNS(namespace, tag);
      for (var k in attrs)
         el.setAttribute(k, attrs[k]);

  return el;
}
angular.module('SvgApp').directive('svgFile', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: 'img/file.svg',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var svgNamespace = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
        var htmlNamespace = 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml';

        var result = makeElement(svgNamespace, "foreignObject",{"class":"point","xmlns":"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","x":"100","y":"100","width":"300","height":"150"});
        var body = document.createElement("body");
        body.setAttribute("xmlns", htmlNamespace);
        body.setAttribute("style", "margin: 0px; height: 100%;");
        var btn = makeElement(htmlNamespace, "button", {"id":"rect3537","type":"button","style":"width:100%; height:100%;","class":"button"});
        var btnSvg = makeElement(htmlNamespace, "svg", {"xmlns":"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","version":"1.1","width":"100%","height":"100%","viewBox":"0 0 50 25"});
        var btnText = makeElement(svgNamespace, "text",{"y":"75%","x":"50%","text-anchor":"middle","font-size":"20","fill":"white"});
        var textNode = document.createTextNode("text");

        btnText.appendChild(textNode);
        btnSvg.appendChild(btnText);
        btn.appendChild(btnSvg);
        body.appendChild(btn);
        result.appendChild(body);

        console.log(result);

        document.getElementById("svg-wrapper").appendChild(result);
    }
  }
}]);
```

file.svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   version="1.1"
   width="100%"
   height="100%"
   id="svg-wrapper">
</svg>
```

Value of result variable:

```
<foreignObject class="point" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="100.0000000000000" y="100.0000000000000" width="300" height="150">
   <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="margin: 0px; height: 100%;">
      <button id="rect3537" type="button" style="width:100%; height:100%;" class="btn btn-primary ng-scope">
         <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%" viewbox="0 0 50 25">
            <text y="75%" x="50%" text-anchor="middle" font-size="20" fill="white">text</text>
         </svg>
      </button>
   </body>
</foreignObject>
```

I don't know why it shows me just empty button without text. Tested on Chrome 52 and Firefox 48.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like this is wrong, you need the svgNamespace as the first argument

```
var btnSvg = makeElement(htmlNamespace, "svg", {"xmlns":"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","version":"1.1","width":"100%","height":"100%","viewBox":"0 0 50 25"});
```

xmlns is not an attribute you should set, it's a consequence of the namespace of the element so I think you want this...

```
var btnSvg = makeElement(svgNamespace, "svg", {"width":"100%","height":"100%","viewBox":"0 0 50 25"});
```

Answer (score 0):

The SVG code in result appears to work (see below), so my guess it is cause by either css rules or possibly conflicts from multiple `<body>` tags and extraneous xmlns declarations. Take a look at your inspector on a rendered version and see if you can find if the text is hidden due to position or css conflicts.

```css
.point {
width: 300px;
height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="point">
      <button id="rect3537" type="button" style="width:100%; height:100%;" class="btn btn-primary ng-scope">
         <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%" viewbox="0 0 50 25">
            <text y="75%" x="50%" text-anchor="middle" font-size="20" fill="white">text</text>
         </svg>
      </button>
</div>
```